# Export vertices as "float4" type

Tags: vertices

So, in order to ensure good data packing in our shaders the vertex position is a float4 type.
I would like to make use of this 4th attribute and encode some custom data in it( a texture array slice index to be exact). Is it possible for us to encode this data in Blender somehow and export the mesh as a fbx ?

I would also be happy with a way to add that value in the UV's, i.e make the uv a float3 not a float2.

Comment: FBX may contain several UV maps, you may use it

Comment: You could also consider encoding this value into vertex colors somehow.

Comment: Yeah, the MeshLoopColor object that represents vertex color data in Blender is currently represented as a float4 array.

Comment: I solved the problem by recreating the mesh uvs as a vector3 in unity with a custom importer